# Issues with the IP link deployed on Amazon ECS and Fargate after applying api_key required in headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, fastapi, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

First of all, I deployed my endpoint to ECS and Fargate without the feature of *api-key is required within the headers*. However, after I added the feature of the api-key in headers, there are several issues happened.

1. Once deployed, I opened the API docs from external IP link, I executed the `/test_api_key` endpoint. The request is working well as it returned the JSON that I have set. But, the second time I requested, it shows the following error -
   [image]

The third time I requested, it loading for a very long time which I am not sure it will return something. I checked the CloudWatch but there is not useful information showed.

2. I closed the tab, then I opened the same external IP link again. This time, the page is loading for a very long time and, the docs not even showed up. I checked the CloudWatch, but there is no useful information showed. Not even the request HTTP log status.

For extra information, I used FastAPI and saved the the `api_key` in .env file that will be loaded from S3 bucket to the container. (due to initial phase development)

If anyone has any idea on why this behavior is occurred knows the solution, please do help. Appreciate it with thank you.

Comment: Check if your load balancer health checks are failing after making that API key header requirement change.

Comment: I don't use any Load Balancer at the moment. Is that the reason why the error is happening? @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by increasing the memory allocated for the Fargate from task definition. Some of my endpoints required a higher amount of memory to work. Previously the memory allocated is 0.5 MB before I increased to 2GB.